# Count number of sentences in textbox

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I am using .cs and aspx file, I have a textbox for user to input the sentences.
I want to create a string/variable(for ex: "i") to detect the number of sentences that user input in the textbox.

the sentences are in string format, and indicates by "." 
for Ex: thank you for the corporation. I hope you doing well.

so it that example, I want my variable "i" results is 2.

I can imagine the split text like :
     `var translateArraySourceTexts = textbox.Text.Split(new Char[] { '.' });`

However, i have no idea for the logic count. I thought using for? please share if you have experienced on this.

Comment: Why did you not google it?

Comment: I think you should split it by `". "`, at least based on your example. `var i = textbox.Text.Split(new string[] {". "}, StringSplitOptions.None).Length;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a count of the number of sentences?

The Split method creates an array, which you have set as `translateArraySourceTexts` so all you need to do is get the length of the array => `translateArraySourceTexts.Length`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is:

```
var translateArraySourceTexts = textbox.Text.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var count = translateArraySourceTexts.Length;
```